# How can I put this fragment on top of the other?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have this view:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/DeepSkyBlue"
    tools:context=".MainPreviewActivity"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <fragment
        android:name="com.apps.foo.bar.CleanPreviewFragment"
        android:id="@+id/clean_preview_fragment"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <fragment
        android:name="com.apps.foo.bar.ProcessedPreviewFragment"
        android:id="@+id/processed_preview_fragment"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/center_dummy_view"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lvImageProcessChoices"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want fragment with id `clean_preview_fragment` to be replaced with fragment with id `processed_preview_fragment`.

My app needs to have a camera running in the background so it gets the frames, processes them and displays them in the `processed_preview_fragment`.

Here is my code:

```
processedPreviewFragment = (ProcessedPreviewFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.processed_preview_fragment);

if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == getResources().getConfiguration().ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.clean_preview_fragment, processedPreviewFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
```

That is in my `MainActivity`, `onCreate`.

I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change container ID of fragment ProcessedPreviewFragment{41b14770 #1 id=0x7f0e0050}: was 2131624016 now 2131624015
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot replace a fragment that was declared via XML. If you want to add fragment to container in runtime, you should use `FragmentManager` to add it. In this case container should be some layout, e.g. `FrameLayout`.

So, replace your `<fragment>` tag in XML with `<FrameLayout>` and add `CleanPreviewFragment` there in runtime. Then, when you need to replace it, use `FragmentTransaction` like you do it now. You shouldn't get that exception anymore.